# Программно вычислить размер шрифта текста, чтобы он был во весь объект

Tags: java, android

Возможно ли это?

Задача: имеются изображения разных размеров, на изображение необходимо добавить текст во всё изображение в высоту и пропорционально в ширину. Необходимо, чтобы шрифт сам подбирался в зависимости от размеров изображения.

Comment: например, группируете `ImageView` и `TextView` в контейнер `FrameLayout`, затем в TextView [используете autosizing](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов с замером высоты изображения (перевода его в sp - по желанию) и установки или установки такового параметра в разметке:

Вариант 1:

```
int imageSize = imageView.getMeasuredHeight()
float sp = imageSize / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
textView.setTextSize(sp);
```

[Вариант 2](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview):

```
android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
```

Пробуйте что вам больше подходит или ищите себе ещё что-нибудь по вкусу.

Comment: в первом варианте зачем получаем imageSize, если оно в примере не используется и откуда взялось px?

Comment: @pavlofff, Не правильно прочитал вопрос. Я подумал что картинки будут добавляться динамически. В принципе такая реализация имеет место быть.